# How to Configure Static IP for Terraform Vertex AI Notebooks Instance?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Terraform Resources: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/notebooks_instance

I checked all documentation about how to create notebook instance via Terraform. But I came across the fact that Vertex Ai Notebooks have Dynamic IPs that complicate the process of distributing access over IP. As a workaround, you can manually create a static IP and bind it in the Notebook VM itself. But I need to do this through Terraform. Since it is possible to  implement the static IP in manual format, so it's possible to implement the static IP in Terraform format. Maybe you have a working sample for that?

I can manually create a static IP and bind it in the Notebook VM itself but I need to do this through Terraform.